# Will Spark structured streaming benefit from dynamic allocation if number of cores more than number of Kafka partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, partitioning, spark-structured-streaming

Supposed we have an application that reads from X partition topic, does some filtering on the data then saves it into storage (no complex shuffling logic, just some simple transformations) using Structured Streaming query. Will this application benefit from dynamic allocation feature that adds more than X single-core executors in case of data spike?

I am asking this, because I've mostly worked with DStreams, where there is quite well known recommendation to have single core per partition so that every executor core will be busy processing data from one partition and adding more executors usually will not give much scaling benefits. My intuition says that no, because the data will still end up on the same workers, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952538/consuming-from-single-kafka-partition-by-multiple-consumers

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about dynamic allocation by yarn ?
But you can use  minPartitions setting in spark structured streaming.
Refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html