# Kafkajs run multiple consumer in single file

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafkajs

I am using kubernetes microserice in which I have create single Kafka micro service to consume all topic and perform its activities. Code sample below:

```
const { Kafka, logLevel } = require("kafkajs");
const kafka = new Kafka({
   logLevel: logLevel.INFO,
   clientId: "kafka9845",
   brokers:["90.45.78.123"],
   connectionTimeout:30000,
   sessionTimeout:30000,
   requestTimeout:30000,
   heartbeatInterval:10000,
   retry: {
      initialRetryTime:5000,
      retries:200
   }
});

const topicGroup1 = ["topic1","topic2"];
const topicGroup2 = ["topic3", "topic4", "topic5"];

const consumer1 = kafka.consumer({groupId: 'consumer1', fromBegining:true});
const funConsumer1 = async ( consumer1 ) => {
   await topicGroup1.forEach((topic) => {
      consumer1.subscribe({topic:topic });
   });
   await funConsumer1.run({
    autoCommit: false,
    eachMessage: async (task) => {
        console.log(task);
        await funConsumer1.commitOffsets([{topic: task.topic, offset : (Number(task.message.offset) +1).toString()}])
    }
  });
 }

  const consumer2 = kafka.consumer({groupId: 'consumer2', fromBegining:true});
  const funConsumer2 = async ( consumer2 ) => {
    await topicGroup2.forEach((topic) => {
      consumer2.subscribe({topic:topic });
    });
    await funConsumer2.run({
      autoCommit: false,
      eachMessage: async (task) => {
        console.log(task);
        await funConsumer2.commitOffsets([{topic: task.topic, offset : (Number(task.message.offset) +1).toString()}])
     }
     });
   }

  consumer1.on('consumer.crash', async (payload) => {
    try {
      consumer1.disconnect();
    } catch(error) {

   } finally {
    setTimeout( async () => {
        await consumer1.connect();
        funConsumer1(consumer1).catch(console.error);
    }, 5000);
   }
 });

  consumer2.on('consumer.crash', async (payload) => {
   try {
      consumer2.disconnect();
   } catch(error) {

   } finally {
     setTimeout( async () => {
        await consumer2.connect();
        funConsumer2(consumer2).catch(console.error);
    }, 5000);
   }
 });


 const funConnect = () => {
   consumer1.connect();
   consumer2.connect();
   funConsumer1(consumer1).catch(console.error);
   funConsumer2(consumer2).catch(console.error);
 }

funConnect();
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
  consumer1.disconnect();
  consumer2.disconnect();
});
```

I am using **"kafkajs":"^2.0.0"** and **"kafka-node":"^5.0.0"**

Everyday we are producing million of message inside different topic

**Problem:** I have analysis consumer processing in queue way.

**Requirement:** Both consumer should consume message in parallel.

Comment: @brian-fitzpatrick please answer to my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Kubernetes, then just make a Deployment for each consumer process. The code provided doesn't have the consumers interacting with one another, so they don't have to be in the same process.

Otherwise, there's no reason that one group/consumer cannot subscribe to multiple topics. You should not use foreach to subscribe, however. [Pass the whole array to subscribe function](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming)

You can check which topic is being consumed from one consumer that is subscribed to multiple topics using a if/switch case within the eachMessage block

Comment: thanks for your message. I have 6 consumer so I can't create 6 different microserivce. Each consumer I have assigned different to different group

Comment: I see no reason you couldn't make 6

Comment: Also as mentioned, I believe each of your consumers is only getting one topic when you're using a foreach loop to subscribe

Comment: I have create group means 1 consumer can subscribe with multiple topic.

Comment: Yes, it can, but wasn't your question about two separate groups working in parallel? One group with 6 topics won't be as scalable as separate deployments

Comment: Yes, one group can read 5 topics... Yes, two groups can read 2 and 3 topics simultaneously, but not in one deployment... You also do not need both kafkajs and kafka-node. Pick only one

Comment: I want some deep understanding of connectionTimeout, sessionTimeout, requestTimeout, heartbeatInterval and reblancing. I have observed I am getting error log for reblancing

Comment: Please open a new post to ask new questions

Comment: Can it's possible to achieve by creating multiple replicas of current microservices.

Comment: Please refer my last comment